# Marshalling null values with a custom type used with an xml adapter

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm using a POJO object with XmlType for a custom XML adapter I built for marshaling a map of strings. I'm having issues however, with getting it to allow me to use null values properly. I was able to get it to work, but I'm not happy with the XML it is generating.

This is what I'm currently using that I would like to work, but as you can see in an sample XML result, it is not including the proper xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" value

```
@XmlType(name="element")
public class RestMapElements {

  @XmlAttribute(name="name")
  public String key;
  @XmlValue
  public String value;

  public RestMapElements(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

The resulting XML (slimmed to relevant data).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
...
    <element-list>
        <item name="activated_date">2012-03-29 11:34:14.323</item>
        <item name="some_null_value"/>
    </element-list>
...
```

However, I was able to get it to work with this, I'm just not happy with the XML having to add an additional "value" tag inside of the item tag to get it to work. (side note, why is it naming it item instead of element like I tried to specify in the XmlType name declaration?)

```
@XmlType(name="element")
public class RestMapElements {

  @XmlAttribute(name="name")
  public String key;
  @XmlElement(nillable = true)
  public String value;

  public RestMapElements(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Again, the resulting XML (slimmed to relevant data).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
...
<element-list>
    <item name="activated_date"><value>2012-03-29 11:34:14.323</value></item>
    <item name="some_null_value"><value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/></item>
</element-list>
...
```

Really, I can use the second as it works to solve my issue. I'm just wanting to use this as a learning experience to see if JAXB using annotations will allow be to bend this to what I'm looking for without having to add that additional value tag underneath an item tag just so I can support null values. Right now, when it unmarshals in the first example, I end up getting empty strings instead of null. In the second example, I get the null value I was expecting.

FYI: I'm currently using Jersey 1.11

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlNullPolicy` extension to map this use case:

**RestMapElements**

```
package forum10415075;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlType(name="element")
public class RestMapElements {

  @XmlAttribute(name="name")
  public String key;

  @XmlValue
  @XmlNullPolicy(nullRepresentationForXml=XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.XSI_NIL)
  public String value;

}
```

**Root**

```
package forum10415075;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="element-list")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<RestMapElements> items = new ArrayList<RestMapElements>();

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following content:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10415075;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10415075/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <element-list>
      <item name="activated_date">2012-03-29 11:34:14.323</item>
      <item name="some_null_value" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
   </element-list>
</root>
```

**Note**

If you are using Jersey in GlassFish 3.1.2 MOXy or WebLogic 12.1.1 is already included:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've seen your other posts regarding other JAXB issues that MOXy solves - we however, are trying to stick to the reference implementation. If we were going to use MOXy, your solution would work!

Comment: Dear @BlaiseDoughan Is there any chance to put `nillable` element on `@XmlValue` in any future JAXB?

Comment: Dear @BlaiseDoughan Oh `nillable` on `@XmlRootElement` would be better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. An `item` element with `xsi:nil="true"` will be generated only by setting the corresponding `RestMapElements` entry in your `ArrayList` (or whatever) to `null`, losing the attribute. I think there isn't much of a solution to this.

One option would be to use your marshalling from the beginning of your post and unmarshal using the following:

If you're doing something like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="element-list")
@XmlElement(name="item")
public ArrayList<RestMapElements> list;
```

You can use a `XmlAdapter` to check if the `value` is an empty `String` and set it to `null` if it is:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="element-list")
@XmlElement(name="item")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ItemAdapter.class)
public ArrayList<RestMapElements> list;
```

And `ItemAdapter`:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends XmlAdapter<RestMapElements, RestMapElements> {

    @Override
    public RestMapElements unmarshal(RestMapElements v) throws Exception {
        if (v.value.equals("")) v.value = null;
        return v;
    }
}
```

Although this is still inelegant imho.
If you want to generate the proper `xsi:nil="true"` `item` elements, this is obviously not what you want though.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to stay away from that solution. I thought of that as well, in just fixing it on the XmlAdapter, but I want the service to be correct so that as others build libraries on our web service they all operate as the same implementation. I'm trying to keep our wrapper library to just be a straight translator from the REST service.